# Rspec with Capybara sometimes not pass tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have problem with testing Rails Application. My tests generally work perfectly. But sometimes tests will fail when I type some features test for modal bootstrap window, or notify with success/error [js]. How can I resolve this problem ? 
I'm using Rspec, Capybara, Rails4.2, PhantomJs, Poltergeist as JS driver. Tests is running locally and in Wercker. In test mode, every bootstrap animation is disabled. What perhaps I do wrong ?
Test:

```
scenario 'return deutsch default title' do
            find('.f-edit-item', match: :first).click
            find('a', :text => 'Lang').click
            find('a', :text => t('menu.languages.de')).click
            find('.f-reset-button', match: :first).click

            expect(page).to have_field('menu_item[title]', with: 'Exhibitions_de')
          end
```

Output:
`Objects Restore Language restore title translations exist for deutsch translation return deutsch default title
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_field('object_item[title]', with: 'Exhibitions_de')
       expected to find field "object_item[title]" with value "Exhibitions_de" but there were no matches. Also found "", "", which matched the selector but not all filters.`

When I click manually, everything is working. When I run this test, sometimes passed, sometimes not. Form is in bootstrap modal. Curiosity: When I add save_and_open_page before `find('.f-reset-button', match: :first).click` test is passed always(5x in a row)

Comment: Can you post an example of a test that is failing, and also the output of Rspec with the failure message?

Comment: @rlarcombe post updated ;)

Comment: How are you disabling the animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the tests are to do with a Bootstrap modal, my guess is that the test is searching the page for the matching elements, BEFORE the modal has loaded in the DOM.

**Edit:** As @TomWalpole pointed out, it should be enough to override Capybara's max wait time like so:

```
expect(page).to have_field('menu_item[title]', with: 'Exhibitions_de', wait: 1.0)
```

But if you are loading the contents of your modal via AJAX, you may need to force a wait for AJAX to complete the *expect* line. [Here is a good guide](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) on how to do this.

Specifically you need:

```
# spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
end
```

And then your test would become:

```
scenario 'return deutsch default title' do
  find('.f-edit-item', match: :first).click
  find('a', :text => 'Lang').click
  find('a', :text => t('menu.languages.de')).click
  find('.f-reset-button', match: :first).click
  wait_for_ajax
  expect(page).to have_field('menu_item[title]', with: 'Exhibitions_de')
end
```

Comment: There is no reason to use wait_for_ajax in this position.  If the 'Lang ' link, etc are in the modal then wait for Ajax isn't doing anything here and if it's the 'Exhibitions_de' field that is being Ajax loaded into a modal then it would just need an increased max wait time - expect(page).to have_field(... , wait: 5)

Comment: @TomWalpole - I think you are right. I will update my answer.